# does anyone know the media query for samsung galaxy s10

Tags: css

I'am having problem with my website in Samsung Galaxy S10. I already got the media query for portrait view but the landscape media query is not working.

Media query that I tried:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (min-device-height: 760px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 4){}
```

Comment: Reverse the width and height?

Comment: It helps to think about what could happen when you turn your device. That has _nothing_ to do with web design.

Comment: May I ask _why_ you need to do this? It seems like your issue is more in your motivation than your attempted solution.

Comment: @domsson the website that iam doing now has two different designs, one for desktop and another one for the mobile device, both designs only have the color in common, everything else is different, you can check it https://dbacademy.in/DBMA/

Comment: @georgephilip I was trying to figure out why you need a media query to target one specific device? There are thousands of devices out there. You surely don't want to write media queries for each. In modern web dev, we try to make our designs work on all (or as many as possible) devices with as little media queries as possible.

Comment: So I can't get the media query for portrait to work at all. I've used the following code but it's like my actual phone/device is completely ignoring it:
`@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (min-device-height: 760px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 4) {}`

The above isn't working though. I also tried going to mydevice.io on my S10, but it shows my viewport width is 412px and when turned landscape it's 778px so I thought I could use those as the width and height, but that didn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I am just posting what's already written in the comments up there, to provide it as answer not as comment.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-height: 360px) and (min-device-width: 760px) and (orientation: landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 4){}
```

As jhpratt already mentioned you just have to reverse the width and height, as you already got the portrait mode view.